# Android Horizontal Recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have implemented Horizontal scrolling in recyclerView but when i swipe right to left next card doesn't comes to center position of the screen, its does infinite scrolling. Swiping left to right to right to left should moves to the next immediate card

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WSiO.png)

[Original Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTMy9.png)

```
Adapter = new CardAdapter1(ProfileList, getActivity(), horizontal_recycler_view); 
final LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false); 
horizontalLayoutManagaer.scrollToPosition(1); 
horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutMa‌​nagaer); 
horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(Adapter); 
horizontal_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);`
```

Comment: You should put your code here!

Comment: **Jay Vignesh**, not in the comment section! Update your question with your complete code snippet included.

Comment: Sounds like you want a ViewPager. RecyclerView doesn't center the views at all

Comment: @cricket_007 kindly provide example for view pager with dynamically adding fragments, since am fetching data from server

Comment: I don't have any examples available. Fetching data from server doesn't matter. ViewPager uses an adapter just like a RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this has something to do **touch event**.Check if your item layout contains ScrollView or similar Element that may react to touch event.

Comment: its recyclerview, i have tried implementing smooth scroller also, when i swipe right to left immediate next card should come to center of the screen